# Draw Lines in ASCII

Tags: ascii-art, code-challenge, graphical-output, printable-ascii

## Challenge

Draw lines in ASCII corresponding to given inputs:

in the first line there are given size of rows and columns of the view and number of separators between each point

in the second line is given list of lines separated by space

a line contains the position of head and tail coordinates (within the size of columns and rows) separated by space (x1 x2 y1 y2).

> In the below examples we used character '#' for filled spot, '.' for free spots and ' ' for the separator but you are free to use any other printable ASCII characters.

Sample input 1:

```
33 15 1
5 0 31 0 31 0 31 10 31 10 27 14 27 14 27 4 27 4 0 4 0 4 0 14 0 14 27 14 31 10 5 10 5 10 5 0 5 0 0 4 31 0 27 4 5 10 0 14
```

Sample output 1:

```
. . . . . # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # .
. . . . # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # .
. . # # . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . # .
. # . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . # .
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # . . . # .
# . . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . # .
# . . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . # .
# . . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . # .
# . . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . # .
# . . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . . # .
# . . . . # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # .
# . . . # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . . # . .
# . # # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # . # . . .
# # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . # # . . . .
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # . . . . .
```

Sample input 2:

```
31 15 0
0 0 30 14 0 14 30 0 15 0 15 14 0 7 30 7
```

Sample output 2:

```
##.............#.............##
..##...........#...........##..
....##.........#.........##....
.....###.......#......###......
........##.....#.....##........
..........###..#..###..........
.............#####.............
###############################
.............#####.............
..........###..#..###..........
.........##....#.....##........
......###......#......###......
....##.........#.........##....
..##...........#...........##..
##.............#.............##
```

**Bonus Points**

Use line position format like so `(y1,x1)-(y2,x2)`.

e.g.

```
31 15 0
(0,0)-(14,30) (14,0)-(0,30) (0,15)-(14,15) (7,0)-(7,30)
```

**Scoring**

This is `code-golf`, so the shortest solution wins.

---

Just to finish this up, simple python(3) answer would be:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVTRbtowFH3nK67oA3YxKClsrYiotI6t0/ZSbXtL8@CQEDwZJ42htVX129m1IdCuYQgcfM7xOfZ1dCu7XpZqdFXV22oq@SrNOGiWT3u9SVULtSY4Udk0p527N/S9eifQe8GkIt17E6aXXdqp/8GuEJs3Ro9sifjCE/HzYz98iZ6XOH47Q5VoVGIihV6TFa8IxjEx1JUUa0Ip7ZyBKuFJqKx80sArAZXUw06mm1RQTe5H5YI3m9dEE6xePnkyaydvPLloJz97Mm0nZ45Usp384sjqBPnVkUveTt46MtPt5HdHyhPkDySf9Iki/PLkiSL8RnL5WJ24OXdvLwt/oPp/kp8o0UXdHrFyr0txKGXNCpa@EtToUOAv9cIzuKlznaslX/U0SKFy4LIoa7FerjpZvoCUmIDZgJmQ2ZBOoAP4yQxMwYQwABPsAIuAdYDdAUaLQiEWglg4@TUEkEudwyD0vH3D23e8T@CpJpmhxwQP2B3Q@GZ24uc@1TAwloHFp3UL/DYYBP7rM73WJR1XZaj29hkuzcxpt8aDHXy9dobUBZw7j0Gz3sv9v0VZgwGhoOaqyPE80Acs5CHFilxmWEeEDZoYx1v841MPqG1Qe1iIBZjBNcYcvXbJfSzrG2gGg/0Oj4ebOdlu1/6eOdnvqZBlyiUIVrE7DzxMBTaMauNaRcRfT/Y9Yd6lUW7yOeneEdIb9obyzwYbzUN8kfRDev4QBwmNJ4MwoVEXZ@7JpzGPxWA8EYmrjzjWZ8xkrgin/TEb0yQqp3ESxeUwN2vsjsR3sJRItGQSnXC4cMMowTbmnKRz4kmkCY3iORFOI1B93myHHvLKJKoJ7Wzx5NvtKITwA95YgO/hKIBwDH4Yubkj3ODBS4dd/gU)

```python
a()
```

or python(1789) *without escape characters:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVTLbtswELznK7buQWQiGVLiIIUA5@RjURS9uoKgSLTNQKYESW7F/ry7S1KvpEENJzR3hrO75JC17k6VevhSN9fVagXfKhUcq/IgCvglmlZWCjB8c/NDtNml7GALNLspxAFeGtEKdcrOrA990PjXRzhGPL4B/BQ9kvsIAuhDG9AY0BTQNtC38qgwFoE8EP0ZQhBlKyCIDK4XuH6HmwzZS8uKnk8ZTEDbwKBbaFuTydpjoRoLxVHTAlOGD6H5mpyGS5mmVQWyjXyBS4v@Y7VBwx91DXeH0D3ckkYwrDd08@tQNdCDVNBk6iiwH7iDYR8NU4qywH3EcI8iPeEaf5isY1QPUT0uxA3YwTOmmbRs5jvc1kVoB4GrcGpuRzRbNZ55XmZtC98rqTp3wmiCNJVKdmnKWlEesOcYu@iwKDPOOiB4bRyxDBlPjOJfpRIfap9EVsQ2vw9dJks3eZuFeKhKwxKgNQjQ4CxcNNnvEnOyVv4RMXSXuhQ@UKSNcWgxUX5q2i3z1p4P3mf6Bx7nEDyDuxE2@bGsXrJyiJlQXmGufTKeL6nSEVv1sbK8Wou@E6pglI9Nl2pxOrTINLbu/dlEuwm1NCJmojnnY@q8Ki9nNfmLut1HyWzjiNVUv99QwjnF2YkhzXeKnPh5teTQZ3gt0D60f5hrQVlerY8Whcnb3FThpy242oLo/xr3ya1h3yfzK@H2Y5CK3knNZFY/1cpgjegujRqgqyR/quws0hS2SEvTcyZVmq6sEgmT18hR7JzVzLhWqvrSMb5u61Li6I4or6qmkCrrREuWkfs4DqLEnImkHd4bZ4wir26556MT@Yw2tTgwAm@GD8kbUZdZLpjHyc7eFFhsgccc6qTQ9rakV6OVJP8qfTbdy2ATy1kX1lcbNKlQbEbkdxjbcKtnLsfy3uTWZCN/OilDXmd1TbeHng5m3gOWoznwiy6lH@hzHwYgGoDIAO4A6obQxWPgXgHOr9eHCKJHfKhZ6Ic8YNHGfwg50EjT0M5CP3q0II7Angz2RNhf)

```python
""" Non-golfed version """

Resault = ""


def bresenham(x0, y0, x1, y1):
    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = y1 - y0
    xsign = 1 if dx > 0 else -1
    ysign = 1 if dy > 0 else -1
    dx = abs(dx)
    dy = abs(dy)
    if dx > dy:
        xx, xy, yx, yy = xsign, 0, 0, ysign
    else:
        dx, dy = dy, dx
        xx, xy, yx, yy = 0, ysign, xsign, 0
    D = 2 * dy - dx
    y = 0
    for x in range(dx + 1):
        yield x0 + x * xx + y * yx, y0 + x * xy + y * yy
        if D >= 0:
            y += 1
            D -= 2 * dx
        D += 2 * dy


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Line:
    def __init__(self, head: Point, tail: Point):
        self.head = head
        self.tail = tail


def drawline(size: tuple, lines: list, chrs=('.', '#', ' ')) -> Resault:
    global Resault
    co = []
    for line in lines:
        co.extend(list(bresenham(
            line.head.x, line.head.y, line.tail.x, line.tail.y)))
    for column in range(size[1]):
        for row in range(size[0]):
            if (row, column) in co:
                Resault += chrs[1]
            else:
                Resault += chrs[0]
            if row != size[0]-1:
                Resault += chrs[2]*size[2]
        if column != size[1]-1:
            Resault += "\n"
    return Resault


if __name__ == "__main__":
    size = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
    coordinates = [i[::-1] for i in [list(map(int, j.split(','))) for i in [
        i.split('-') for i in input().replace(')', '').replace(
            '(', '').split(' ')] for j in i]]
    coordinates = [coordinates[i-4:i] for i in range(4, len(coordinates)+4, 4)]
    lines = []
    for c in coordinates:
        lines.append(Line(Point(c[0][0], c[0][1]), Point(c[1][0], c[1][1])))
    print(drawline(size, lines))
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! For future reference, I highly recommend using the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140) before posting so you can get feedback, suggestions, and clarifications first. This challenge idea looks quite interesting but the I/O format needs a bit more work before it's suitable and I'm a bit confused by how the scoring system works, and if it's even a good idea to deviate from standard code golf here. This is definitely much better than the previous post though so some work in the Sandbox would help this a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your input, very appreciated. i was going to edit some stuff but since is closed ill comment it on sandbox. @hyper-neutrino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 84 bytes, score unknown

```
≔⮌Ｉ⪪Ｓ θＵＯ⊟θ⊟θ.ＦＩＥ⪪Ｓ Ｅ⪪ι-⪪✂λ¹±¹¦¹,«≔Ｅ²↨Ｅι§μκ±¹ηＦ⊕⌈↔η«≔⁺·⁵Ｅ§ι⁰⁺λ∕×κ§ημ⌈↔ηκＪ⊟κ⊟κ#»»ＵＥ⊟θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFNboMwEIXXcAqLbsaSE5mmURZZpT@LVGobNbkAATdY2IaAiSJVOTudgdBs2gUazzz85uOR5kmdlonpulXT6IODT3VSdaPgKWk8bCujPaxd1fqtr7U7ABcsYhHnWI98GX7sTYnTTVnBEUdjjaYRil9lzQaft6T630uwm6xxNKHR0G6NThUYwWLB3tUh8QpiFOmJBFFwzr7D4IpONveCPSaIT2c0W/m1y9QZrGAFMf@a4DlHxKBnXLu0VlY5rzK8eNa2tbDaN6Vp8d183DKu2Zi2ATmdD9zjBlwmKQESEfhZn3SmYKetaqC4geSCWd5/8l9rSCkIK3htbbUr@2CLa7CDsMHoPER3FHBwCS/hy9krl11/AV923Sxm8ZzJEKSQfALxg5hJzqhSK4dOing@iFgZLHptQVo3OZkf) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⮌Ｉ⪪Ｓ θ
```

Input the first line, split on spaces, cast to integer and reverse.

```
ＵＯ⊟θ⊟θ.
```

Draw the background of the desired size.

```
ＦＩＥ⪪Ｓ Ｅ⪪ι-⪪✂λ¹±¹¦¹,«
```

Input the second line, splice on spaces, split each piece on `-`, chop off the `()`s, split again on `,`, cast to integer, and loop over the sets of coordinates.

```
≔Ｅ²↨Ｅι§μκ±¹η
```

Calculate the difference between the start and end points.

```
Ｆ⊕⌈↔η«
```

Loop over the number of steps needed to draw the line.

```
≔⁺·⁵Ｅ§ι⁰⁺λ∕×κ§ημ⌈↔ηκ
```

Interpolate between the start and end point.

```
Ｊ⊟κ⊟κ#
```

Jump to the calculated position and output a `#`.

```
»»ＵＥ⊟θ
```

Space the output horizontally as desired.